# read() and write() using spi device driver

Tags: c, linux, spi

I would use the read() and write() for the /dev/spiB.C which is created by the user mode spi device driver (spidev.c). Now, the SPI ransaction message follows a certain format (e.g., 24 bits, with some bits for address and some bits for data) which is defined by the chip-vendor-specific spi controller driver. How is the message format fit into the read() and write() transaction? Where and how should I define the format in the code before or after the write() or read()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call spidev_ioctl() mentioned in spidev.c

E.g. Just check switch case :SPI_IOC_RD_BITS_PER_WORD which sets the bits/word (line 410).

Then finally it writes to the bits_per_word member in the spi device structure (line 415).

This spi pointer is the pointer of the spi device which you are communicating to and has been allocated during spidev_probe().

Definitely you need to set the configuration before r/w.You also need to set speed and mode of SPI.

I have refered to the below link for spidev.c file:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c